# Migrate all CI/CD pipelines from an Azure DevOps project into another instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure DevOps project and do have many CI/CD pipelines in the same project.
There are around 200+ CI and CD pipelines which are inside different folders.

Now there is a requirement that I have to move all the CI and CD pipelines into another Azure DevOps project which is in another instance.

I tried to copy the main folder which contains all subfolders and pipelines, but didn't see any option like that. I could see only importing option for each pipeline separately. But it is not practical to import 200+ pipelines manually.

Is there any method to import the complete pipeline folder and export to new instance. We  could create service connections in the new instance with same name.

Any leads appreciated! Thank you in Advance.

Comment: By the API, you can export/import pipeline.

Comment: could you please share if any document available ?

Comment: [Azure Pipeline API - Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines)

Comment: I have seen the API to get list of pipelines available, but is there any way to export all the pipelines ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, since the pipelines are created using classic editor in the portal page, the pipeline code is available nowhere. We have to export each pipelines manually using export to json/yaml option. then the same has to be imported to new devops instance. Tedious and Time consuming, but didn't see any other option as of now.

Answer (score -2):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to bulk migrate pipelines into different collection/organization/project. You need to export and import them one by one.

You can create a feature request to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest), Azure DevOps product team will assess it seriously based on its comments and votes.

Comment: Is there any work around to achieve this ?